# virt-manager copy and paste,is possible to disable it?

Tags: qemu, spice

I use virtual machines with virt-manager and kvm-qemu.
Simple question: on VirtualBox I can enable the addon 
for auto-resize of screen,and I like it.

I also disable copy and paste because I want
separate clipboards with guest and host.

How to disable copy and paste but mantein auto-resize
on kvm-virt-manager and spice?
Is possible?

Comment: I could not find a way to do this (after adding `<clipboard copypaste='no'/>` to my guests), but I've written an ugly hack to change a guest's resolution over SSH based on the size of the SPICE window: https://gist.github.com/ivan/9e1bf24c1b6ae4f1fe9587b55d3f9544

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how auto-resize in Virtualbox works, but I also searched for disabling clipboard sharing through Spice on my Linux system. Ivan Kozik's comment above pointed me in the right direction, but did lack some information which i had to gather and want to share:

1. You need to have **libvirt** package installed to use **virsh**.
2. Type in terminal: `virsh edit NAME` where NAME is the name of your guest. The Domain XML is opened with **vim** in your terminal. If you are not familiar with the commands, find yourself a [cheat sheet](http://vimsheet.com).
3. Under `<devices>` find `<graphics>` and inside add the line 
    `<clipboard copypaste='no'/>`. Save and exit. 
    For further information search in their [docs](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsGraphics).
4. Restart the guest. And you will notice that the clipboard sharing is gone.